# How to guarantee counter synchronisation between client and server for counter in hmac-based one time password implementation?

Tags: hmac, one-time-password

We are trying to implement a hmac-based one time password protocol for use authenticating users over our api.

The idea is to encrypt a unique identifier for the user (uid) against a private key and an incremental counter. Then increment the counter for the next call.

```
encrypt(uid, private_key, counter)
# now increment the counter for the next call
```

Then on the server side, decrypt using the private key and the counter to get the user identifier (uid).

```
decrypt(encrpyted_string, private_key, counter)
# now increment the counter for the next received request
```

This works fine. Each call is completely unique (one time) because of the counter.

However how would we handle synchronisation of the counter? What happens if the client generates a request, increments the counter for the next call, and sends the request, but the server is offline and never receives the request, or there is an internet connectivity issue and the request never gets through - now the server and the client are out of sync with each other's counters.

Is this a case of "you should know if a request has been submitted"? I.e. we could add a response header from the server to say whether the counter has been incremented and *only if it has do we increment the counter in the app too*... but then the same could be said the other way around - we could send a request, the server receives it, increments its own counter  and sends a response, but the internet connection has been interrupted whilst the server was processing its request and the app never receives the response, never increments its counter and therefore the two are out of sync again.

Thanks for any insight you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

To synchronize counter between server and client just check some range of OTP. If Client sends OTP for current counter - all is ok, it is nothing to do, if client sends OTP in some range near current counter (~15) - it's mean, that client can be authenticated, but you need update counter on a server.
In a case when there is big desynchnization you should ask two consistent OTP and check if they was correct on wide range of counters. If it was - set your server counter to founded value.